# Kylin odbc driver C++ solution fails to build

Tags: c++, odbc, zlib, kylin

I am unable to build **Kylin ODBC** C++ solution.

I followed the instructions found [here](https://github.com/apache/kylin/blob/master/odbc/README.m), unfortunately, I get an error when I try to build the solution.

I am getting the below error message:

> Error LNK1181 cannot open input file
>   'zlibstat.lib'    Common  C:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\kylin-master\odbc\Common\LINK   1

When I include the `zlibstat.lib` file, I get an error message saying that it is already included.

Answer (score 0):

The Error looks like your ***zlibstat.lib*** cannot be found.

Please check whether ***ZLIB_HOME*** is set in Environment Variables and whether project zlib is well compiled.

You can verify with check in file ***Common.vcxproj*** .
For example you want to build with Release|x64, please check whether can find ***zlibstat.lib*** in location $(ZLIB_HOME)\contrib\vstudio\vc11\x64\ZlibStatRelease.